# Trouble with c# and TextMode="Number"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a trouble with c# and textmode="number", the following occurs: I add camp textmode="Number" a Textbox for Numbers, it turns out that for some strange reason Visual Studio 2012 sends me this error :

> Error 6 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxMode' no contiene una
>   definición para 'Number' C:\Users\Alejandro
>   Fernandez\Desktop\MarketVenezuela\market_RegistroEmpleado.aspx 77

What I understand is that is not in your library, but if I put option should not accept ?

Answer (score 1):

check your target framework in web.config file...
you should have the 4.5, like this:

```
<compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="C#" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Comment: According to msdn: targetFramework can takes a values "2.0|3.0|3.5|4.0", but your answer really helped to me. Error was appear when advanced precompile setting 'Allow precompiled site to be updatable' not checked and targetFramework set to "4.0" in Web.config. If change it on targetFramework="4.5" everythings becomes good.